# Some questions about testing a PSU using a multimeter

Tags: power-supply

I've been getting poor performance in all my games despite normal thermals for the past six months.

On HWInfo, the voltage is shown to be only ~10.8V on the 12V rail and ~4.5V on the 5V rail. I'm looking to test this manually with a multimeter and find out whether this is a cause of low performance.

I have a couple of questions about this:

- Most video tutorials tell you to connect the multimeter to a 4-pin molex connector, but I don't have this connector on my PSU. However, I do have a smaller floppy drive power connector with similar red, yellow and black wires. Can I use this instead?
- Do I need to unplug my motherboard, hard drive and other components while testing the PSU, or can I test it with all of them plugged in and with the computer on?
- Considering that my issue is primarily low gaming performance, can the multimeter accurately detect voltage when the GPU is drawing power and the PSU is under high load?

Even if I can't trace the low-performance issue directly to the power supply, there is clearly some kind of problem with it — this is because it sometimes trips the breaker. This usually happens when the power comes back after a power cut. This never happens with any other device in my home.

Comment: If your system was under full voltage load, that would be a bad thing, it would be mean your PSU wasn't powerful enough for your system.  It's very unlikely your performance problems are because of your PSU.

Comment: It is very important to note that voltage values reported from motherboard sensors are usually garbage. They’re so inaccurate you might as well ignore them completely.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't been able to isolate it to any other thing. I have no idea what could be causing this issue. Also there is no explanation for why my PSU trips the breaker.

Comment: @DanielB I do understand that, and that is precisely why I want to test it with a multimeter. On some occasions, the reported values can end up being accurate too.

Comment: Regardless of the actual issue, I'd still like to be clear on the three questions I asked about using a multimeter to test the PSU. Maybe there is a marginally low voltage that's causing problems even when under load. I'd at least like to cross that off the list.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe I lack an understanding of basic electronics, but isn't only the wattage supposed to be variable? Shouldn't the voltage be constant irrespective of load?

Comment: Voltage will drop when overloaded. Also, just because the value may coincidentally be near the real value doesn’t make the measurement accurate.

Comment: The threshold is + or - 5%.  You are way under the limit you probably need a PSU with more watts.  The floppy drive cable can be used for voltage testing.

Comment: Okay. Can I test the voltage with the PSU still connected to the motherboard and with the computer on? Is that safe?

Comment: *"Can I test the voltage with the PSU still connected to the motherboard and with the computer on?"* -- Yes.  *"Is that safe?"* -- YMMV.  I could do it without harming myself or the PC.